# Set ImageView from Bitmap (null pointer exception)

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-sdcard

So my app has an `ActionDialog` which contains a blank canvas as the interface with simple cancel and save buttons. What is happening is best demonstrated in a brief illustration

Screen layout before

-(TextView)-(ImageView)-(Button)-

Then when the user presses the button the `ActionDialog` pops up requesting they sign. Once they sign the captured drawing is saved. Then the drawing is accessed via memory and placed where the original `ImageView` is with a `bitmap`. However this is what ends up happening

Screen Layout after

----------nothing--------------

They just disappear and I get an error in my `logcat`:

```
05-14 19:06:27.004: E/Error(25274): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0signature.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-14 19:06:27.004: E/BitmapFactory(25274): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0signature.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0signature.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

It does not crash my program though. Anyways here is the code for the files

**action dialog**

```
public class CaptureSignature extends DialogFragment {
Sign sign;
View view;

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder capSig = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    capSig.setView(sign = new Sign(this.getActivity(), null))
            .setMessage(R.string.store_question)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.save,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            try {
                                sign.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                                sign.getDrawingCache()
                                        .compress(
                                                Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,
                                                10,
                                                new FileOutputStream(
                                                        new File(
                                                                getActivity()
                                                                        .getExternalFilesDir(
                                                                                "img"),
                                                                "signature.png")));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("Error ", e.toString());
                            }
                            File mysig = new File(getActivity()
                                    .getExternalFilesDir("img"),
                                    "signature.png");
                            ImageView sig = (ImageView) getActivity()
                                    .findViewById(R.id.sig_image);
                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mysig
                                    .getAbsolutePath());
                            sig.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                        }
                    })

            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        }
                    });

    // Create the Dialog object and return it
    return capSig.create();
}
}
```

So obviously I've messed this up somewhere. If anyone has any insight I would be grateful. Thanks!

I personally think I am either saving this wrong or I'm not correctly declaring Sign, as in I call it but I don't give it a value, so the `drawing cache` is not actually being accessed.

**Edit**
I have declared this in the `Manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**2nd Edit**

showing new code and logcat, the error has changed

**final edit**

Thank you very much Matt Giles and JRowan, this was driving me insane. It works now and the above code is the final version.

Comment: is that it, are you instantiating the actual sign that your using, because it sets the view new Sign, maybe thats returning null drawing cache

Comment: try this:::::  capSig.setView(sign = new Sign(this.getActivity(), null))

Comment: @JRowan unfortunately that did not fix the problem, I sincerely wish it had. I have updated my post to show all the new code/logcat

Comment: do you have read_external_storage in your manifest

Comment: read not write, your getting permission denied to read i think

Comment: I added it just now, and re ran. Still getting the same error... dang, I thought you had it. I was so excited to add that to the manifest

Comment: before sign.getDrawingCache() try to put sign.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Comment: @JRowan same error after adding that. I see where you're going with this though and it makes perfect sense. Everytime you post a comment I'm like "thats gotta be it!" only to be dissappointed when it doesn't work

Comment: i got it hold on, i think i know what it is

Comment: try Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "signature.png" in the place of both your file calls

Comment: Matt Solved it, I will post the solution Momentarily, however my imageview is now pushing the other objects on my screen up and down a LOT. I may need to start another thread on how to solve that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "signature.png"
```

The call to `getPath()` returns a path that doesn't have a trailing '/'. Hence the file path in the error message, `/storage/emulated/0signature.png` instead of `/storage/emulated/0/signature.png`.

It would be better to use application-specific storage, instead of putting files in the sdcard root directory. Instead of the `new File(...)` call you have now, use:

```
new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir("img"), "signature.png")
```

`getExternalFilesDir(name)` creates a folder called "name" that's dedicated to your application. This prevents your app from cluttering up the sdcard root directory.

Comment: indeed I have my friend, sorry I did not mention that. I will add it to the post. Also am i not doing what you recommned by using the line `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"signature.png"`

Comment: No, getExternalStorageDirectory() returns the path to the sdcard root. getExternalFilesDir(someName) returns a folder on the sdcard dedicated to your application for storing files. This way the sdcard root isn't cluttered up with files.

Comment: Thank you @Matt Giles, I will check the answer right now but what you just taught me about adding a folder to the root directory is invaluable. I was unaware. So for that, Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. You don't have to use "img" or any presets in there, the folder name can be whatever you want, and you can have multiple ones for different types of files.

Comment: Well my app is still giving me the same error after removing the `.getPath()` method. Any other thoughts or code you would like to see?

Comment: Does it give the same error if you use getExternalFilesDir(...) instead? Right now it's trying to read a file called 0signature.png in the /storage/emulated folder, and your app doesn't have permission to access that (it shouldn't).

Comment: I wouldn't know how to create the folder to be used or where to declare that in my class. If you'd like to show me with some psuedo code that would be great. I currently get red lines saying I should change to getExternalStorage... or create a method/class etc.

Comment: You're right, my code wasn't correct for inside your listener. The method needs to be called on the Activity object. Updated my example.

Comment: Ha! it worked! now for the last question, and god i hope it's simple. Why is this now shoving everything else on my screen up 300dp and down 300dp. How do I set the constraints to make this thing match_parent inside it's `linearlayout` like the its side views `TextView` and `Button`

Comment: Glad that worked. Not immediately sure on the new problem, might be worth making another question with more details.

Comment: Yep gonna do that if I can't figure it out, usually not a problem I can't do but who knows. Thanks again!